# fundamental questions regarding approximations of tensors

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra, tensor-decomposition

**My situation:**

I'm an absolute beginner regarding tensors and Ive currently working on a manuscript about a format which approximate / represent tensors of possibly high order. But before I can start with that, I need to clarify basic questions. I know they are trivial, nevertheless I hope for your help.

So first **the definition** of a tensor:

A tensor  $ \chi \in \mathbb{C}^{{n_1} \times ...\times {n_d}} $  is a $d$-dimensional array with entries $ \chi_{i_1...i_d} \in \mathbb{C}$.
Usually, $d$ is called the order of the tensor.

the **first approximation** is:

$ vec(\chi) = u_d \otimes u_{d-1}  \otimes ... \otimes u_1 , \quad u_1 \in \mathbb {C}^{n_1}, ... , u_d \in \mathbb{C}^{n_d} $

where $vec$ stacks the entries of a tensor in reverse lexicographical order into a long column vector and $ \otimes $ denotes the standard Kronecker product.

So here is my **first request**:

1. Can you give me an example for the first approximation?

So lets say $ \chi \in \mathbb{C}^{ 2 \times 3 } $ with

$$\left(
\begin{matrix}
    1 & 3 & 10 \\
    2 & 5 & 7 \\
\end{matrix}
\right) $$

what exactly is $vec(\chi)$ now? Is it:

$$ 
\begin{pmatrix} 7 \\ 5 \\ 2 \\ 10 \\ 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

and what is $ u_1 \otimes u_2 $ in this special case?

2. the **second approximation** is a more general Canonical Polyadic decomposition:

$ vec(\chi) \approx \sum_{j=1}^R u_d^{(j)} \otimes u_{d-1}^{(j)}  \otimes ... \otimes u_1^{(j)} $, $ \quad u_1^{(j)} \in \mathbb {C}^{n_1}, ... , u_d^{(j)} \in \mathbb{C}^{n_d} $

so my **second question**: Can you explain this to me? I mean I don't know what $ R$ is. An trivial example might help me here as well.

Actually I have more questions, but I dont want to go beyond the scope.

Thank you for your help.